# No Worker Parallelism During Presto Query on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-emr, presto

I have set up a presto cluster on AWS EMR querying from an S3 Bucket. I am exploring the cluster overview metrics as I run queries, and I notice that even though there are 2 available worker nodes, there is 0 worker parallelism. I was wondering why that was.

[cluster overview image of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGipo.png)

Answer (score 3):

Worker parallelism is a metric showing how much CPU you use across the nodes. If you do not query Presto, or queries are not CPU intensive (e.g. are bottlenecked on IO), you will not see worker parallelism.